# Can the name of the bundle application be different of the name of the executable file?

Tags: cocoa, xcode5, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed login item whose executable file name is something like X174423.MyApp because it is prefixed with my developer ID. I'd like to set the bundle name for this helper application to MyApp.

In Xcode 5, I've tried to change the bundle display name but the name of the bundle does'nt change.

I've created a CFBundleDisplayName entry in the InfoPlist.strings but the name of the bundle reminds the same.

It seems that I've missed something but what ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to have the bundle to be shown in Finder as MyApp. I don't know why exactly it has to be like this, but it's working for us the following way.  In your Apps Info.plist:

```
  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>X174423.MyApp</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>X174423.MyApp</string>
```

and following in the InfoPlist.strings:

```
  /* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */
   CFBundleDisplayName = "MyApp";
   CFBundleName = "MyApp";
```

Alternatively you could try this in Info.plist and don't use InfoPlist.strings:

```
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>X174423.MyApp</string>
  <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
  <string>MyApp</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>MyApp</string>
```

Comment: Apple says : Login items must have filenames that match their bundle identifiers. A login item with the bundle identifier "XYZABC1234.com.example.iDecideHelper" would have a filename of "XYZABC1234.com.example.iDecideHelper.app".

I'd like that the name of the helper bundle located in the main application bundle is not prefixed with my developer ID. But the executable will.

I've tried the solutions that you give (thank you) but the name of the helper bundle never changes, it's always the name of the bundle identifier. It's the case under Xcode 5 for sanboxed applications (main and helper).